# Let R be the relation defined on the set of real numbers by xRy iff x=y or xy=1

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

Give the equivalence class of 3, -2/3, and 0.

I'm unsure if the equivalence classes for these should just be {3,3}, {2/3,2/3}, and {0,0}. If they extended to the xy=1 condition, I'm unsure about what they would look like in that case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $3$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{3}$ because of $3\cdot\frac{1}{3}=1$, so the class belonging to $3$ is the set {$\frac{1}{3},3$}. The class belonging to $0$ is {$0$} because if $x=0$ there is no $y$ with $xy=1$ (the same if $y=0$)

Comment: You seem to think that an equivalence class is an ordered pair.  Equivalence classes are in fact *sets* and depending on the relation these sets could have any number of elements in them.  Specifically, $[3]$, the equivalence class of $3$ is the set $\{x~:~x\mathcal{R}3\}$.  Remember that a number is only written a *single time* in each set.  You would never write a set $\{3,3\}$ you would only write it with the element appearing once $\{3\}$.  What numbers are related to $3$?  $3$ is related to three.  Any others?  How about zero?  What number or numbers are related to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Several comments here.

**First**, it would be good to verify that $ R$ is indeed an equivalence relation.

**Second**, you note sets like $\{0,0\}$... While this is not incorrect, you should notice that for whatever element $a$, you have $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$.

**Third**, the equivalence class you mentioned are not correct. For example you have
$$\overline{3}=\{3,1/3\}$$

**Fourth**, the equivalence class of $0$ is a "special case". Do you see why?